# Angular js drag and drop

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I want to have drag and drop feature in the following structure.
[image]

Im using [this](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists) library to make the above structure draggable. 
But it has certain conditions to follow.

- Main Parent is not draggable.
- Main Parent can have any number of children.
- Children can have any number of items.

Lets take Child 4.1. Say Item1 is of type admin and Item2 and Item3 are type users. **Child can have only one admin but can have any number or users**.

Next the condition for the child elements.

- Child 4 has Child 4.1, but child 4.1 cannot have a inner child 4.1.1.
- Child can move only upto level 3.
- Child can be dragged from level 3 to level 2 and vice versa.

In this case, Child 3 can be dragged to as Child 4.2 and Child 4.1 can be dragged to as a new Child 5 or level 3 child named Child 3.1.

Im trying to integrate [nested](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested) and [type](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/types) drag and drop to achieve this structure.

**EDIT 1**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/salman92/t5bqrh38/3/) of what i have achieved so far.

Here type checking is done between **'men' and 'woman'**. Each container can have **only 3 men and 2 woman**. 
Now I want to make the list/child draggable and to be drop inside other list/child and these children will be inside one main parent which cannot be dragged

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="types.html">
        <ul dnd-list="list.people" 
        dnd-allowed-types="list.allowedTypes"
        dnd-dragover="dragoverCallback(index,type,list,((list.people | filter:{type: 'men'}).length >= list.maxM),((list.people | filter: {type: 'woman'}).length >= list.maxW))" 
        dnd-drop="dropCallback(index, item, type)"
        dnd-disable-if="(list.people.length >= (list.maxM+list.maxW))">

          <li ng-repeat="person in list.people" 
          dnd-draggable="person" 
          dnd-type="person.type" 
          dnd-moved="list.people.splice($index, 1)" 
          dnd-effect-allowed="move" class="background-{{person.type}}">
            <dnd-nodrag>
              <div dnd-handle class="handle">:::</div>
              <div class="name">
                <input type="text" ng-model="person.name" class="background-{{person.type}} form-control input-sm">
              </div>
            </dnd-nodrag>
          </li>
          <li class="dndPlaceholder">
            Drop any <strong>{{list.allowedTypes.join(' or ')}}</strong> here
          </li>
        </ul>
      </script>

  <div class="typesDemo">

    <div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">List of {{list.label}} (max. {{list.max}})</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" ng-include="'types.html'"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your solution?

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal Its a really long code. I have added many conditions to satisfy my needs. The library has callback listeners. dragStartCallBack, dragoverCallback, dropCallback, insertedCallback. I wrote my conditions in these callbacks. returning false will not have any change in the model.

Comment: you can call these callbacks through the html.
dnd-dragover="dragoverCallback(event,list,type,index)", dnd-drop="dropCallback(event,list,item,index)",  dnd-inserted="insertedCallback(event,list,item,index)", dnd-dragstart="dragStartCallBack(list,item,$index)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the callback listeners to satisfy my needs.

```
dnd-dragstart="dragStartCallBack(list,item,$index)"
dnd-dragover="dragoverCallback(event,list,type,index)"
dnd-drop="dropCallback(event,list,item,index)"
dnd-inserted="insertedCallback(event,list,item,index)"
```